# Subset data to contain only label of columns whose names match a condition

Tags: r, regex, subset, contains, hmisc

I have the following sample data frame:

```
M <- c(1, 2)
S <- c(3, 4)
old_df <- data.frame(M, S)
label(old_df$M) <- "My Mathematics Variable"
label(old_df$S) <- "My Science Variable"
```

And I want to filter in order to only have columns that contains "Math" in the label of the columns.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can use `grepl`:

```r
old_df[, grepl("Math", label(old_df))]
# My Mathematics Variable 
# [1] 1 2
```

data

```r
library(Hmisc)
old_df <- structure(list(M = structure(c(1, 2), label = "My Mathematics Variable", class = c("labelled", 
"numeric")), S = structure(c(3, 4), label = "My Science Variable", class = c("labelled", 
"numeric"))), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: In this case, works, but I guess that in my original dataset, the label is not in "string format". When I use this same code all the columns disappear

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean. Could you edit your question and add a minimal example where the solution does not work?